# Windows application to see clipboard contents (hex/text)

Tags: windows, clipboard, hex-viewer

I am looking for a tool (free) that makes it possible to see the **clipboard** contents in different formats.

It would be nice to have a **hex editor** inside it in order to see the true contents of the clipboard.

I want to analyse text contents that includes some invisible characters. Basically I want to **see the contents that are in RAM** for example when I copy a cell in a Excel sheet. It should work on **Windows**.

Basically something like Wireshark for the clipboard. Where you can analyse the bits and bytes and where you see the contents human readable.

**Screenshot of Free Clipboard Viewer 2.0 (Thanks to RockPaperLizard)**

[image: Hex View]

You can see the binary data of your clipboard like in a Hex editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The program [Free Clipboard Viewer](http://freeclipboardviewer.com/) will display the contents of the clipboard in all the different formats in which it is designed to be represented.

It won't show data in a format for which it wasn't designed, which is good because it won't waste your time, but bad because it won't satisfy your curiosity.

Comment: It shows Hex format! It is all what is needed!